# .load() not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a page by using jQuery AJAX. It works inside Dreamweaver live, but inside Chrome, FireFox and IE9 it's not working. Please help me.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#pag1').click(function() {
        $('#cont').load('pag1.html');
      });

      $('#pag2').click(function() {
        $('#cont').load('pag2.html');
      });
    });
  </script>

  <a id="pag1" href="#">the page 1</a><br/>
  <a id="pag2" href="#">the page 2</a><br/>
  <div id="cont"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: I am sure you have a wrong path to jQuery - look in the Network console for 404. Also note the version of jQuery >=2 does not run in IE9

Comment: Also are you opening this page from file system or server? if it is `file://` protocol ajax is restricted by most browsers for security reasons

Comment: Is it working in *any* browsers?

Comment: @jeffdill2 "Chrome, FireFox and IE9" pretty much.